# houston apn push doesn't do anything (no errors)

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to use Houston to send a push notification. I recreated the provisioning profile, can upload a device token successfully, but when I push using apn the console shows no readout. Is there a way to log what APN is doing? (Submitted a github issue; posting here hoping someone's ran into this.

Running this code returns nothing. I've tried removing spaces & <> from the device token too, same result.

```
Using rspec 3.1.0
Using simplecov-html 0.8.0
require 'houston'

# Environment variables are automatically read, or can be overridden by any specified options. You can also
# conveniently use `Houston::Client.development` or `Houston::Client.production`.
APN = Houston::Client.production #tried development, same result
APN.certificate = File.read("/Users/quantum/Documents/cliqupprodcerts.pem")


# An example of the token sent back when a device registers for notifications

token = "tokentoken"
# Create a notification that alerts a message to the user, plays a sound, and sets the badge on the app
notification = Houston::Notification.new(device: token)
notification.alert = "Hello, World!"

# Notifications can also change the badge count, have a custom sound, have a category identifier, indicate available Newsstand content, or pass along arbitrary data.
notification.badge = 57
notification.sound = "sosumi.aiff"
notification.category = "INVITE_CATEGORY"
notification.content_available = true
notification.custom_data = {foo: "bar"}

# And... sent! That's all it takes.
v = APN.push(notification)
puts v
~
```

EDIT: I had tried production before, production & development don't work. puts notification.errors after sendings shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check whether you have had a develop profile that has a permission to push remote notification.

Then if your device is iOS 8.0 or later ,`"Please use registerForRemoteNotifications and registerUserNotificationSettings: instead");`

The last, you can do follow the steps of **`"houston"`**

Comment: Yes; I wasn't the only one of this problem https://github.com/nomad/houston/issues/80 https://github.com/nomad/houston/issues/72